# Why is Entity Framework creating additional columns using foreign keys as primary keys?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I have 4 entities which I would like to create relations for. These are the classes with fluent API configurations:

```
public class BusinessEntity
{
    public int BusinessEntityId { get; set; }
    public BusinessEntityAddress BusinessEntityAddress { get; set; }
}

public BusinessEntityConfiguration()
{
    HasKey(b => b.BusinessEntityId);
}

public class Address
{
    public int AddressId { get; set; }
    public string StreetName { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string AreaCode { get; set; }

    public BusinessEntityAddress BusinessEntityAddress { get; set; }
}

public AddressConfiguration()
{
    HasKey(a => a.AddressId);
}

public class AddressType
{
    public int AddressTypeId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public BusinessEntityAddress BusinessEntityAddress { get; set; }
}

public AddressTypeConfiguration()
{
    HasKey(a => a.AddressTypeId);
}

public class BusinessEntityAddress
{
    public int BusinessEntityId { get; set; } // should act as FK with  BusinessEntity and part of composite PK

    public int AddressId { get; set; } // should act as FK with Address and part of composite PK

    public Address Address { get; set; } 
    public int AddressTypeId { get; set; } // should act as FK with AddressType and part of composite PK

    public AddressType AddressType { get; set; }

    public BusinessEntity BusinessEntity { get; set; }
}

public BusinessEntityAddressConfiguration()
{
    HasKey(b => new { b.BusinessEntityId, b.AddressId, b.AddressTypeId }); 
    HasRequired(b => b.BusinessEntity).WithOptional(be => be.BusinessEntityAddress);
    HasRequired(b => b.Address).WithOptional(a => a.BusinessEntityAddress);
    HasRequired(b => b.AddressType).WithOptional(at => at.BusinessEntityAddress);          
}
```

So for the `BusinessEntityAddress` table I expect to have 3 columns:

```
BusinessEntityId, AddressId, AddressTypeId
```

Each should be a FK with its respective table and together should be a the primary key. Instead I get this migration:

```
public partial class test : DbMigration
{
    public override void Up()
    {
        CreateTable(
            "dbo.BusinessEntityAddresses",
            c => new
                {
                    BusinessEntityId = c.Int(nullable: false),
                    AddressId = c.Int(nullable: false),
                    AddressTypeId = c.Int(nullable: false),
                    Address_AddressId = c.Int(nullable: false),
                    AddressType_AddressTypeId = c.Int(nullable: false),
                    BusinessEntity_BusinessEntityId = c.Int(nullable: false),
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => new { t.BusinessEntityId, t.AddressId, t.AddressTypeId })
            .ForeignKey("dbo.Addresses", t => t.Address_AddressId)
            .ForeignKey("dbo.AddressTypes", t => t.AddressType_AddressTypeId)
            .ForeignKey("dbo.BusinessEntities", t => t.BusinessEntity_BusinessEntityId)
            .Index(t => t.Address_AddressId)
            .Index(t => t.AddressType_AddressTypeId)
            .Index(t => t.BusinessEntity_BusinessEntityId);
    }
    
    public override void Down()
    {
        DropForeignKey("dbo.BusinessEntityAddresses", "BusinessEntity_BusinessEntityId", "dbo.BusinessEntities");
        DropForeignKey("dbo.BusinessEntityAddresses", "AddressType_AddressTypeId", "dbo.AddressTypes");
        DropForeignKey("dbo.BusinessEntityAddresses", "Address_AddressId", "dbo.Addresses");
        DropIndex("dbo.BusinessEntityAddresses", new[] { "BusinessEntity_BusinessEntityId" });
        DropIndex("dbo.BusinessEntityAddresses", new[] { "AddressType_AddressTypeId" });
        DropIndex("dbo.BusinessEntityAddresses", new[] { "Address_AddressId" });
        DropTable("dbo.BusinessEntityAddresses");
    }
}
```

So my question is why are these:

```
Address_AddressId = c.Int(nullable: false),
AddressType_AddressTypeId = c.Int(nullable: false),
BusinessEntity_BusinessEntityId = c.Int(nullable: false)
```

extra columns being created and why are they being used as FKs and indexes. Any assistance appreciated.

Comment: I am not sure, but it could be because you have added composite PK

Comment: You may be right but my logic is that if it is possible have a relationship like this in a SQL database then it should be possible to create this type of relationship with Entity Framework as well.